# How to temporarily disable iPhone SIM card?

Tags: iphone, network, sim

It's easy to disable wi-fi connections or cellular data, but how does one disable connections to cellular networks?

Three obvious solutions:

- use Airplane mode.
- remove SIM card.
- explicitly set the network to a different carrier.

The first also turns off wi-fi, the second is awkward and inconvenient, and the third burns CPU as it continually tries to connect to the wrong network.

Is there an easy way to say that I want to use wi-fi without any cellular connection?

(In case it makes a difference, this is specifically for an iPhone-8.)

Comment: Have you tried enabling Airplane mode then manually turning on WiFi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable Airplane Mode without disabling Wi-Fi or Bluetooth.

When you enable Airplane Mode, if it disables Wi-Fi just tap to re-enable Wi-Fi. It will remember your preferences for the next time you enable Airplane Mode.

Comment: Ah, I thought that Airplane mode overrode those other settings; it never occurred to me that one could still transmit while in Airplane mode.  (And given its purpose it still sounds like Airplane mode *should* override the others.)  Thanks.

Comment: Disabling Wi-Fi and Bluetooth is not required on most airlines. Only cell service disabling is required in the US.

Comment: This seems such a pointless exercise, switch it all off then switch one back on again… vs, just switch off the one you don't want.

Comment: @Tetsujin The cellular switch only disables cellular data, which the original question acknowledges. It doesn't disable phone calls. And, as I mentioned it remembers the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth settings so for most people tapping Airplane Mode only disables the cellular connection and no further interaction is required.

Comment: Ah, OK. [Had to wait for my partner to get home to test that.] I didn't know they weren't equivalent.